# Querying CosmosDB in R-shiny

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, azure-cosmosdb

Does anyone know how to run dyplr queries on a CosmosDB from R?

I have an R-shiny app with input sliders that create filters for a CosmosDB.

To give an example of a static query

```
install.packages("AzureCosmosR")
require(AzureCosmosR)

query_documents(cont, "SELECT c.mpg FROM mtcars c WHERE c.cyl=6 AND c.gear=4
                ", metadata=FALSE)
```

How could I create something like `c.cyl=!!input$cyl` from an input slider like you would with a dyplr filter?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options to explore:

1. Use the glue package to create suitable queries:

```r
query_string = glue::glue("SELECT c.mpg FROM mtcars c WHERE c.cyl={inputs$cyl} AND c.gear=4")
query_documents(cont, query_string, metadata=FALSE)
```

The glue package looks up items within curly brackets `{ }` as if they were variables in your environment.

2. Use dbplyr to automatically translate dplyr commands into SQL. The tidyverse intro to dbplyr is [here](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/). But this will likely require some work to get R talking to your database.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful! I was originally using dbplyr with a SQL database connected through MariaDB and that worked nicely but haven't found the right driver for the CosmosDB variety. I will explore option 1 and get back to you.